# My first Configuration DNS doesn't work or respond on centos

Tags: centos, dns, bind, tcp-ip

for studying purposes about TCP/IP, we should run a DNS server, i did the advised configuration, the server is runing without any erros, but when i request the server for the configured domain name with dig or nslookup command, i get nothing.

Here are the settings:
system : centos 7.
installation of bind package :
`yum install bind` 
configuration of /etc/named.conf

```
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//
// See the BIND Administrator's Reference Manual (ARM) for details about the
// configuration located in /usr/share/doc/bind-{version}/Bv9ARM.html

options {
   listen-on port 53 { any; };
   listen-on-v6 port 53 { any; };
   directory   "/var/named";
   dump-file   "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
   statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
   memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
   recursing-file  "/var/named/data/named.recursing";
   secroots-file   "/var/named/data/named.secroots";
   allow-query     { any; };

   /* 
    - If you are building an AUTHORITATIVE DNS server, do NOT enable recursion.
    - If you are building a RECURSIVE (caching) DNS server, you need to enable 
      recursion. 
    - If your recursive DNS server has a public IP address, you MUST enable access 
      control to limit queries to your legitimate users. Failing to do so will
      cause your server to become part of large scale DNS amplification 
      attacks. Implementing BCP38 within your network would greatly
      reduce such attack surface 
   */
   recursion yes;

   dnssec-enable yes;
   dnssec-validation yes;

   /* Path to ISC DLV key */
   bindkeys-file "/etc/named.root.key";

   managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";

   pid-file "/run/named/named.pid";
   session-keyfile "/run/named/session.key";
};

logging {
       channel default_debug {
               file "data/named.run";
               severity dynamic;
       };
};

zone "." IN {
   type hint;
   file "named.ca";
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";

zone "mydomaine.fr" IN {
   file "/var/named/mydomaine.zone";
   type master;
   allow-update {none;};
};
```

configuration of /var/named/mydomaine.zone

```
$TTL 1D

mydomaine.fr.   IN  SOA ns1.mydomaine.fr.   root.mydomaine.fr.(
0; serial
1D; refresh
1H; retry
1W; expire
3H; minimum
)

mydomaine.fr.   IN  NS  ns1.mydomaine.fr.
ns1 IN  A   192.168.10.1
```

when i run `systemctl status named.service -l`

```
● named.service - Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS)
  Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/named.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
  Active: active (running) since Fri 2022-01-28 19:19:32 CET; 11min ago
 Process: 3597 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named -u named -c ${NAMEDCONF} $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Process: 3594 ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c if [ ! "$DISABLE_ZONE_CHECKING" == "yes" ]; then /usr/sbin/named-checkconf -z "$NAMEDCONF"; else echo "Checking of zone files is disabled"; fi (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
Main PID: 3599 (named)
   Tasks: 5
  CGroup: /system.slice/named.service
          └─3599 /usr/sbin/named -u named -c /etc/named.conf -4

Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: zone mydomaine.fr/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: zone localhost.localdomain/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: zone 1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.ip6.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: zone 1.0.0.127.in-addr.arpa/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: zone localhost/IN: loaded serial 0
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: all zones loaded
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: running
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Started Berkeley Internet Name Domain (DNS).
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: managed-keys-zone: Key 20326 for zone . acceptance timer complete: key now trusted
Jan 28 19:19:32 localhost.localdomain named[3599]: resolver priming query complete
```

and `dig mydomaine.fr`  gives me :

```
G 9.11.4-P2-RedHat-9.11.4-26.P2.el7_9.8 <<>> mydomaine.fr
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NXDOMAIN, id: 23167
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 0

;; QUESTION SECTION:
;mydomaine.fr.          IN  A

;; Query time: 7 msec
;; SERVER: 192.168.132.190#53(192.168.132.190)
;; WHEN: Fri Jan 28 19:20:25 CET 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 30
```

and the command `nslookup mydomaine.fr`   gives me :

```
Server:     192.1...
Address:    192.1...#53

** server can't find mydomaine.fr: NXDOMAIN
```

Comment: You mention ".fr" to which registrar is your domain recorded ? did you ensure that your nameserver is referenced properly by the registrar ? if nobody reference your nameserver for your domain, nobody will find it.

Comment: If your domain is not registered, what gives ```dig yourdomain.fr @<ip of your name server>```  that would drives you toward firewall issue btw.

Comment: Thank you @dominix for your answer, this server is for learning purposes, so i'm running it localy, when i execute the commande `dig mydomaine.fr @<ip of your name server>` my local server respond correctly, but when i execute `dig mydomaine.fr` i get nothing, do you have an explaintion for that, and thank you again !

Comment: you need to set your resolver to question your nameserver. edit ```/etc/resolv.conf``` and set as the only nameserver the ip off yours.```nameserver <ip of your name server>```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mydomaine.fr` isn't associated with an IP address in your config.
You should add an A record that would associate it with the desired IP address.

```
$TTL 1D

mydomaine.fr.   IN  SOA ns1.mydomaine.fr.   root.mydomaine.fr.(
0; serial
1D; refresh
1H; retry
1W; expire
3H; minimum
)

@             IN  NS  ns1.mydomaine.fr.
ns1           IN  A   192.168.132.190 ;your bind server IP
@             IN  A   192.168.10.1 ;IP mydomaine.fr points to
```

The **@** symbol substitutes the current (or synthesized) value of `$ORIGIN`. You can also omit it. In your case `$ORIGIN` inherited zone name from named.conf file (mydomaine.fr)

Comment: @goler3 still have last question, why `dig mydomaine.fr` i dont get response, but for `dig mydomaine.fr @IPofServer ` does work

Comment: It's because you're default DNS server is not your local DNS server but some global DNS server (like Google for example) You could change your system's DNS server but that's another topic since it depends on which service is responsible for it. For the sake of exercise you can modify it in /etc/resolv.conf to your local DNS IP but it most probably won't survive reboot... But you can do it and then try dig without @ServerIP, it should work

Answer (score 0):

You want to set `ORIGIN` up correctly, as in `$ORIGIN mydomaine.fr.` before the `ns1` entry, then restart.

Try `dig ns1.mydomaine.fr.`. That is the only entry you have setup, or `dig -t ns mydomaine.fr.`.

When you do dig or nslookup without a RR type, it will default to `A`. Your config has no `A` RR type against `mydomaine.fr.`.

This should work...

```
$ORIGIN .
$TTL 43200      ; 12 hours
mydomaine.fr. IN SOA  ns1.mydomaine.fr. root.mydomaine.fr. (
  0          ; serial
  172800     ; refresh (2 days)
  14400      ; retry (4 hours)
  3628800    ; expire (6 weeks)
  604800     ; minimum (1 week)
  )
  NS      ns1.mydomaine.fr.
$ORIGIN mydomaine.fr.
ns1 A 192.168.10.1
```

And try `host ns1.mydomaine.fr` rather than dig.

And you may need `allow-query { any; };` in the named.conf zone definition. It's a bit of a sledgehammer approach though.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133738/discussion-on-answer-by-bib-my-first-configuration-dns-doesnt-work-or-respond-o).